# How to break block loop in Objective - C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iteration, block, break

I have these declarations in header file:
**Note:** *I won't explain the whole code, I think it is easy to understand*

```
typedef void (^loopCell)(id cell);
-(id)allCells:(loopCell)cell;
```

And **allCells** function implementation:

```
-(id)allCells:(loopCell)cell
{
    for (AAFormSection *section in listSections)
    {
        for (id _cell in section.fields) {
            cell(_cell);
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The usage of **allCells** function:

```
-(void)setFieldValue:(NSString *)value withID:(int)rowID
{    
    [self allCells:^(id cell) {
        if([cell isKindOfClass:[AAFormField class]]) {
            AAFormField *_cell = (AAFormField *)cell;
            if(_cell.rowID == rowID) {
                _cell.value = value;
                //return; Here I want to terminate loop
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

**My problem is**, I can't **terminate** allCells loop in the middle (actually when I found object I need in the loop, I don't want iterate through other objects)
How can I stop allCells loop in the middle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the docs for `NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`. They setup the block signature to take a BOOL pointer. Set the stop BOOL to YES to cause the iteration to stop.

```
typedef void (^loopCell)(id cell, BOOL *stop);

-(id)allCells:(loopCell)cell {
    BOOL stop = NO;
    for (AAFormSection *section in listSections) {
        for (id _cell in section.fields) {
            cell(_cell, &stop);
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

-(void)setFieldValue:(NSString *)value withID:(int)rowID {    
    [self allCells:^(id cell, BOOL *stop) {
        if([cell isKindOfClass:[AAFormField class]]) {
            AAFormField *_cell = (AAFormField *)cell;
            if(_cell.rowID == rowID) {
                _cell.value = value;
                if (stop) {
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been thinking about almost similar way, now it is more clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't break from `setFieldValue`, but you can from `allCells`.

It's up to the method you're using that calls the block — `allCells` in this case — to provide a mechanism for stopping the loop. Usually, it's a parameter to the block.

If allCells is yours and you don't mind modifying it, you modify the block signature to take a pointer to a BOOL, initialized to YES, and check if the block modified it to NO.

(Note: You can `break` from a for in loop.)